# Disable dropdown list option based on parameter value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following code. I want that the second option will be automatically disabled if `value==0`. I know i can disable the option by adding the class `disabled` inside the `<li>` tag, but how can add this class according to the parameter value?

```
function analysisActions(key, value){

  var str= '<div class="dropdown">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions '+
      '<span class="caret" style="border-top:4px solid white"></span></button>'+
      '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'+
        '<li><a href="#" data-target="#A_form" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key +'" id="a_' + key + '">A</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="#" data-target="#B_form" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key +'" data-id="' + key + '" id="b_' + key + '">B</a></li>'+
      '</ul>'+
    '</div>';

return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function analysisActions(key, value) {

    var disabledStr = value == 0 ? ' class="disabled" ' : '';
    var disable = value == 0 ? ' disabled' : '';

    var str = '<div class="dropdown">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions ' +
        '<span class="caret" style="border-top:4px solid white"></span></button>' +
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
        '<li><a href="#" data-target="#A_form" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key + '" id="a_' + key + '">A</a></li>' +
        '<li' + disabledStr + '><a ' +  disable  + ' href="#" data-target="#B_form" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key + '" data-id="' + key + '" id="b_' + key + '">B</a></li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>';

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but for some reason, when i click on the disabled option, the pop up dialog popped up. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

it's simple `use if value == 0`  before adding `li` to the string.If `value == 0` add the class `class="disabled"`

```
  var str = '<div class="dropdown">' +
  '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions ' +
  '<span class="caret" style="border-top:4px solid white"></span></button>' +
  '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
    '<li><a href="#" data-target="#A_form" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key + '" id="a_' + key + '">A</a></li>';
        if (value == 0) {
            str += '<li class="disabled"><a href="#" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key + '" data-id="' + key + '" id="b_' + key + '">B</a></li>';
        }
        else {
            str += '<li><a href="#" data-target="#B_form" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-id="' + key + '" data-id="' + key + '" id="b_' + key + '">B</a></li>';
        }
        str += '</ul>' +
'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but for some reason, when i click on the disabled option, the pop up dialog popped up. Do you know why?

Comment: @Supertwister I have updated the answer , I have removed `data-target="#B_form"` and `data-toggle="modal"`,so when `value == 0` , it will not open the modal